# compare two dates using conditional formatting pd.xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I have a dataframe as below. Now I need to use conditional formatting to highlight the entire row in red if  due date < today's date.

I tried the below code, but I'm getting an error saying 'TODAY' is not defined.

```
date = TODAY()

worksheet.conditional_format('C1:C6', {'type':     'date',
                                   'criteria': 'less than',
                                   'value':    date,
                                   'format':   red})
```

[image]